# in winhex i am trying to locate data size of a bzip2 compressed file?

Tags: linux, compression, bzip2

I am trying to find the compressed file size of a Bzip2 file in winhex but don't know how to do it, can anyone know how to find these things by looking at hex editor

i have tried checking the file of header i.e 42 5A 68 but still don't know what to do next?

Comment: By "compressed file size" do you mean the size of file compressed in `bzip2` file (already compressed file) or you mean size of original uncompressed file?

Comment: like i have compressed a file (already compressed) now I have opened it in winhex for research so i have to find the size of file using hexeditor by looking at their hex values but i don't know how to read size of data by information provided after the header ( magic number ) of bzip2

Comment: @MarkAdler, not exactly, there are headers and footers (with variable size)

Comment: so how should i find the file size

Answer (score 2):

When you check the [headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2#File_format) of `bzip2` you will see first you have 4 bytes as header

```
BZh<0-9>
```

then you have in `BCD` coded `Pi` number (6 bytes):

```
0x314159265359
```

then CRC (4 bytes)
etc...

then it start Huffman encoded data stream (which by my understanding is the compressed data)

and at the end you have `SQRT(Pi)` in `BCD` (6 bytes)

```
0x177245385090
```

CRC (4 bytes)

and 0 to 7 bits padding (to whole byte)

Comment: exactly this is what i want to know the size of the huffman encoded data Stream ( size of compressed data ) is there any specified offset which is designated for data size just like CRC n all

Comment: @Devlupur, you should decode `*.delta_bit_length:1..40` because as you can see it vary of length. Which mean the data stream may not start on exact byte, it can be in the middle of byte. Also `.huffman_used_bitmaps:0..256  ` vary so you should check it also.... The best you can do id to get the source of `bzip2` and analyze it https://gitlab.com/bzip2/bzip2/

Comment: if i calculate *.delta_bit_length:1..40 is the compressed size of the data stream will be same

Comment: @Devlupur, no. As I point better check the source code.

Comment: like i am not using code i am viewing the file in hex editor for research so I have to find the compressed size just by looking at the hex values

Comment: and i have texted you on your Instagram profile check it out so I can send you the picture

Comment: @Devlupur, if you do not decode properly the headers you can't be sure where it start the data stream.

Comment: and how exactly i decode the header , tell me please